# How to detect if a class has a templated member function?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters

###### I know some codes that can detect if a class has a member function, like below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename F>
constexpr auto has_member_impl(F&& f) -> decltype(f(std::declval<T>()), true) { return true; }
template<typename>
constexpr bool has_member_impl(...) { return false; }
#define has_member(T, EXPR) has_member_impl<T>( [](auto&& obj)->decltype(obj.EXPR){} )

class A{
public:
  void operator()(int data){ cout << data << endl; }
};

class B{
public:
  template <class CLASS>
  void func_int(CLASS &c, int data){ 
    if constexpr(has_member(CLASS, operator()(int()))) c(data);
  }
  template <class CLASS>
  void func_string(CLASS &c, std::string data){
    if constexpr(has_member(CLASS, operator()(std::string()))) c(data);
  }
};

int main(){
  A a;
  B b;
  b.func_int(a, 1); // print out 1
  b.func_string(a, "2"); // print out nothing, unless class 'A' defines 'operator()(string);'
}
```

where,

- class A holds a member function 'operator()'
- in class B, functions 'func_int' and 'func_string' use constexpr(has_member(...)) to detect if 'operator()(int)' and 'operator()(std::string)' exist in a CLASS, respectively. If yes, execute that function.

###### When the member function of class A is a template function, the code can be something like below,

```
class A{
public:
  template <typename T>
  void operator()(T data){ cout << data << endl; }
};

class B{
public:
  template <class CLASS, typename DATA>
  void func(CLASS &c, DATA data){
    if constexpr(has_member(CLASS, operator()(1))) c(data);
  }
};

int main(){
  A a;
  B b;
  b.func(a, 1); // print out 1
  b.func(a, "2"); // print out 2
}
```

where, the part of constexpr statement is changed to 'operator()(1)'

###### This time I want to make it more complex, like below

```
class A{
public:
  template <typename T>
  void operator()(T data1, T data2){ cout << data1 << ' ' << data2 << endl; }
};

class B{
public:
  template <class CLASS, typename DATA>
  void func(CLASS &c, DATA data1, DATA data2){
    if constexpr(has_member(CLASS, operator()(1, 2))) c(data1, data2);
  }
};

int main(){
  A a;
  B b;
  b.func(a, 1, 2); // print out '1 2'
  b.func(a, 1, "2"); // print out '1 2' (I want to make it print out nothing)
}
```

where,

- in class A, the function 'operator()' accepts two parameters of the **same type**
- it seems that the constexpr statament in class B can use any argument 'operator()(x,y)' to detect its existence, no matter whether the two parameters are of the same type

What I want to know is that '**when the function of A is a template function, how to detect if the two parameters are of the same type?**'

Comment: Your first examples test if specific code that invokes a member function works.  They don't detect if a member function exists.  This is a subtle difference.  Without reflection, only duck type tests can be done.  So you need to phrase your requirement in terms of duck type operations

Comment: `1,2` are hard coded, how about `template <class CLASS, typename DATA> void func(CLASS &c, DATA data1, DATA data2){ if constexpr(std::is_invocable_v<CLASS, DATA, DATA>)) c(data1, data2); }`?